# Big-O of Nested-for-loops: Linear or Quadratic?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, nested-loops, asymptotic-complexity

I am trying to understand how to know if nested-for-loops in an algorithm yield  linear or quadratic [Big-Oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) complexity. Here are a few examples I came-up with, but are related to brute-force-loop-up and graph-traversing. I try to

Am I on the right path of thinking?

**Example 1:**

```
N = ? // Number of elements in an array of integers
For i = 1 to N
    For j = 1 to N
        Print "foo"
```

- *Complexity:* O(N^2)
- *Why?* Because we have two nested-for loops that are going to iterate same amount of times. Because we don't know the value of N during run-time, then we have to say complexity is O(N^2)? However, if we hard-code N=20, then we would have O(N)?

**Example 2:**

```
N = ? // Number of elements in an array of integers
For i = 1 to log(N)
    For-each edge of log(N)
        Print "foo"
```

- *Complexity:* O(log(N)^2)
- *Why?* Because we have two nested-for loops that are going to iterate same  log(N) amount of times.

**Example 3:**

```
V = ? // Total number of nodes in a graph
E = ? // Total number of edges in a graph (not of each iteration-node)
For i = 1 to V
    For j = 1 to E
        Print "foo"
```

- *Complexity:* O(V*E)
- *Why?* Because we don't know if V = E, so we cant say O(V^2) or O(E^2). We don't know if V>=E or V<=E. So we just say O(V*E) to cover all cases.

**Example 4:**

```
V = ? // Total number of nodes in a graph
For i = 1 to V
    For-each edge of V[i]
        Print "foo"
```

- *Complexity:* O(|V| + |Edges in Graph|)
- *Why?* Because we know that |Edges in Graph| != |V|, so the number of iterations is not proportional. Does this matter when graph is Directed vs. Undirected?

Comment: There are no `n`'s in any of your examples, so it never makes sense to say `O(n)` or `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Sorry compiler. I have fixed case-sensitive issues

Comment: Also, you do not know that |E| > |V|; a graph can have lots of vertices and no edges at all, for example. If you *do* have a graph where that's true, then `O(|V|+|E|) = O(|E|)`.

Comment: Agreed. Correct way is to say that |E| != |V|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big-O notation describes how the running time of an algorithm changes with respect to the size of the input.

With example 1, if you hardcode N as 20, then there is no scaling with input. The algorithm actually becomes `O(1)`.

Example 2 is similar to your intuition of example 1, except that each loop only runs log(n) iterations.

With example 3, I'd describe this as running in `O(mn)` time (m = number of edges, n = number of vertices), rather than `O(n^2)`.

The last example is actually slightly more nuanced than I first gave it credit (thanks, @Hurkyl!).

The edges are partitioned by the vertices, so effectively you run the inner loop a total of `2|E|` times, in addition to running the outer loop `|V|` times. This leads to your algorithmic complexity of `O(|V| + 2|E|)`. Constants are generally ignored in big-o notation, so this is considered the same as `O(|V| + |E|)`.

Comment: Phylogenesis: I added one last example. Please take a look at it. My appologies.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: You aren't thinking through the third (now fourth, since the edit) example; the inner loop executes exactly `2|E|` times.

Comment: @Hurkyl Good point. You're absolutely right - I shall fix my answer.